# Do you move a surveyor when they are already on the westmost tile?

Tags: carcassonne-new-world

In *Carcassonne: New World*, you need to move the eastmost surveyor one tile to the west every time a feature is completed *and* scored. However, it is quite possible to finish a feature while both surveyors already are on the westmost tile(s). How to proceed?

I see several possible options:

1. Move a surveyor one step to the west, to where the next column is going to be.
2. Do not move a surveyor.
3. Draw an extra tile, place that to the west of the westmost tile and place the surveyor on it.

This situation is not found in the rules, at least not in my version (in Dutch, where the game is called *Carcassonne: Mayflower*).

The [FAQ at BoardGameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/34615/new-world-carcassonne-game#results_7) says that option 2 is the correct one. It does seem the most likely, but is there an official source for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching a bit more, I came across [the rules of the American version](http://riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_262_gameRules.pdf). They state quite clearly that surveyors don't move if they can't.